# Is $\{y_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ a bounded sequence if $\{\|z-y_n\|\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{y_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence in $\Bbb{R}^n$ and $z\in\Bbb{R}^n$ be given. If $\{\|z-y_n\|\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a convergent sequence, what can we say about $\{y_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$? More precisely, can we conclude that $\{y_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is bounded?

For some reason, I'd like to extract a convergent subsequence from $\{y_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, and this can be done by showing that $\{y_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is bounded. Here is my attempt. Since $\{\|z-y_n\|\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges, it must be bounded. Then $\exists r>0$ s.t. $\forall n\in\Bbb N$, $\left|\|z-y_n\|\right|<r$, but this amounts to saying that each term of $\{y_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ falls into an open ball centered at $z$. Thus, $\{y_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ must be a bounded sequence. Is my attempt correct, please? Thank you.

Comment: How about $\|y_n\| \le \|z\| + \|y_n - z\|$?

Comment: @Integrand Thank you, but I'm afraid that we can't infer that $\{z-y_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges. For example, the sequence $(-1)^n$ diverges although the sequence of its absolute values converges.

Answer (score 1):

Translating a bounded set preserves its boundedness.

Proof.

Suppose $B$ is bounded and $y\in\mathbb{R}^d$.    Put $b = \sup\{\|x\|: x\in B\}$.  Then for $x\in B$, $$\|x + y\| \le \|x\| + \|y\| 
\le \|y\| + b.$$

We conclude that $\sup(y + B) \le \|y\| + \sup(B).$

Comment: Thanks for improving you post; I've deleted my no longer relevant comment.

Comment: I was hoping the OP would pick up the baton and prove this for himself.

Answer (score 0):

If $x_n$ is a real-valued sequence then $x_n \to x$ implies that for some large $N$, $|x_n-x|<1$ for $N \leq n$.  Now let $M=max_{n<N}\{|x_n|\}+1+2|x|$ and notice that $|x_n| \leq |x_n-x|+|x|$

Answer (score 0):

First let the sequence WLOG be unbounded from above, i.e. for each $z\in R$, $\exists k$ such that $y_k>z$. Now let $\epsilon>0$ be given, if $|z-y_n|$ converges then there is some $m$ such that for all $q>m$, $|z-y_q|\leq \epsilon$, which implies that $y_q\leq z+\epsilon$.
But this contradicts with the unboundedness of the sequence $y_n$, since the finite set $\{y_o\},o=1,…,m$ is definitely bounded, and for each $j>m$, $y_j\leq z+\epsilon$. Let $b=max(sup\{y_o\},z+\epsilon)$, we can’t find $k$ such that $y_k>b$.